# OpenGL DSA equivalent for glReadPixels

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, glreadpixels, direct-state-access

I'm trying to retrieve a Pixel-value from a Renderbuffer attached to an unbound Framebuffer.
Since I'm trying to avoid changing global state when reading said value I'm unable to use `glReadPixels([...])` which would normally be used to read Pixels from the currently bound Framebuffer.

`DirectStateAccess` methods usually solve this problem but I'm unable to locate a method that allows for directly specifying the source of the read operation.

Is it possible to read the pixel in a different way, without having to bind the associated `Framebuffer`? Why did this method not get included in the DSA extension?

Comment: "*Pixel-value from a Renderbuffer attached to an unbound Framebuffer.*" Is there a reason you couldn't do the read while it was bound?

Answer (score 1):

If the framebuffer attachment is a [Texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture)  and not a [Rrenderbuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Renderbuffer_Object), you can read the pixel data from the texture object instead of the framebuffer with  [`glGetTextureImage`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTexImage.xhtml).